# How to install ubuntu from CD

Tags: installation, windows, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I recently downloaded ubuntu and am having trouble installing it. I have converted the image to a CD using InfraRecorder and set BIOS to launch from CD/DVD. Whenever I start the computer I just get a flashing command prompt for about 10 seconds and the it launches Windows from the hard drive. How do I get it to recognize the CD and launch from it? My end goal is to reformat my hard drive and install ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I am new so cannot comment, hence leaving this as an answer.

You appear to have done the correct things so I would have to ask: did you burn the ISO as a complete image, or did you just copy the files to the CD? If you did the latter, it will not boot. Secondly, I would double check the md5 sum of the CD image, just to make sure it downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO you downloaded should be write in to the cd as an image file.If you are on windows use this software "Imageburn" which can be downloaded from this page http://download.imgburn.com/SetupImgBurn_2.5.7.0.exe and install it.Select write image and go through the instructions.Put the cd in drive and reboot system.Most of the modern computers boot from cd itself,otherwise please change the boot order in BIOS.Moreover visit this page too for more info. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD